# как правильно сделать replace для 2 колонок?

Tags: mysql, sql, replace

как правильно обработать все значения в 2х колонках?

```
UPDATE e.x_receivers
    SET scan_1 = REPLACE(scan_1, '%files/viewid%', 'files/view?id='),
        scan_2 = REPLACE(scan_2,'%files/viewid%', 'files/view?id=')
   where   (scan_1  LIKE "%files/viewid%" or scan_2  LIKE "%files/viewid%");
```

выше код матчит значения, но не меняет содержмое

для 1 столбца работает как нужно

```
UPDATE e.x_receivers
    SET scan_1 = REPLACE(scan_1, 'files/viewid', 'files/view?id=')  where   (scan_1  LIKE "%files/viewid%" or scan_2  LIKE "%files/viewid%");
```

Comment: `SET column = CASE WHEN {condition} THEN {new value} ELSE column END`

Comment: проценты `%` из `replace` уберите и будет все работать